# Perl script halts when using XML::LibXML + DBI

Tags: perl, dbi, libxml2

I have the following script in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dbname = "test";
my $dbhost = "localhost";
my $dbuser = "user";
my $auth = "password";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$dbname:$dbhost", $dbuser, $auth);

print "The end\n";
```

When I run it, it outputs "The end" and then just halts without any errors or warnings.
I'm running it on FreeBSD 9.1, Perl 5.12.4

It works fine without "use XML::LibXML;" or without "my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$dbname:$dbhost", $dbuser, $auth);"

I tried to run it in gdb. It executes just if it was all fine, but stops on the following lines, without terminating:

[New LWP 100828]
[New Thread 80187d000 (LWP 100828/perl5.12.4)]

Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Gone when upgraded to Perl 5.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had once a problem when using `GD` and `XML::LibXML` together in a script on FreeBSD. See http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=171353 . In a nutshell, try to recompile perl from ports with the PTHREAD option turned on.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reported bug:  [Bug #64743 for DBI: XML::LibXML + DBI = bus error](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=64743)

Comment: A bug of what? They just say this is not a DBI bug, that's all. If this is a compatibility issue between, say, certain version of Mysql and some Perl module, it would be nice to know what steps should be taken exactly.

Comment: Gone when upgraded to Perl 5.16